# Connection string problem with New ASP.Net Website template

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

This is the connection string that gets generated with the "New ASP.Net Website" template in vs 2010

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ApplicationServices"
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I have a named instance of sql 2008 developer edition installed. I have changed the Server name but the query string will still not work.  I want to be able to use the default db "aspnetdb.mdf".  I use Windows authentication to connect.  How can i change the connection string to get this to work?

Comment: Note that you can find the exact connection string in Visual Studio by going to Server Explorer → [Your database] → Properties → Connection String. It helped me in the past.

Comment: What error message do you get when you try using this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attaching to a database via `AttachDBFilename` is [only possible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254504.aspx) when you use one of the Express editions of the product. So it won't work on the developer edition.

Since user instances [will be removed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143684.aspx) in a future version of SQL Server, you probably shouldn't use this.