# ASP.NET - database is not attached from file automatically

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have created simple `ASP.NET MVC 5` web page using `Entity Framework 2`. After finishing and testing this application I decided to migrate it to my friend's computer. So I copied entire folder with Visual Studio solution to his computer.

Unfortunately while starting app this error occurs:

> Cannot create file [database path] because it already exists. Change
>   the file name, and retry the operation.  CREATE DATABASE failed...

The problem is that my friend does not want to create a new database, he wants to use this specific database file (`DB.mdf`) provided by me. So this file should by attached to LocalDB but is not.

The connection string is:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DB.mdf;Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: It's look like your app try create db which name is DB.mdf, but you copy it with app. So you have to look in your code? There is no problem with some method which create db?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure DB.mdf is located in the application App Data folder and attach it to your local db *manually* before running the application.

<strike>If EF does not see a db attached to localdb with the name 'db' it will try to create it which is what is blowing up because the file it wants to make is already there. it is NOT smart enough to see the file and just know to attach it for you.</strike>

It appears you are correct, must have changed somewhere along the line.

I think this SO may be of more help to you.
[How does one Attach to an MDF file created by Code First using Server Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28201591/how-does-one-attach-to-an-mdf-file-created-by-code-first-using-server-explorer)

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately nothing has changed. And on my computer when I delete connection from `SQL Server Object Explorer`, and run application it is created again and everything works fine.

Comment: So you have a database attached to localdb named db already and still see the error?

Comment: no, DB is not attached to LocalDB, I want this DB to be attached automatically while running application, as it is on my computer (it is working on my computer well).

Comment: That's not how ef works. If it does not see a db named 'db' it will try to create it, if it DOES see one already attached called 'db' it will try to migrate it. 
On your computer it created a NEW database once you removed the connection from Server Object Explorer, it did not attach the existing file as that was DELETED. If you only detach it locally and then run the app you will see your error happen.

Comment: So explain me: I detached my localdb on my computer, and run application. Database from file has been attached aumatically - I can see that because all of data is loaded properly (like rows saved before)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28201591/how-does-one-attach-to-an-mdf-file-created-by-code-first-using-server-explorer