# why I can't create SQL database in VS 2010?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I want to create a SQL Server database in `App_Data` folder, but alert pops up saying:

> Connections to SQL server database files (.mdf) require SQL Server
>   2005 Express or SQL Server 2008 Express to be installed and runnin on
>   the local computer

[image]

But I have this installed:

[image]

What's wrong with that? I need help:/

Comment: Is the MSSQLSERVER service running?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127359/how-to-add-sql-server-database-file-mdf-in-visual-studio-without-installing-s

Comment: no,actually no services related to SQL Server is running :/

Comment: You have **SQL Server** installed - but it looks like it's not an **EXPRESS** edition. This "attach the .mdf file" feature is **EXPRESS** only - but you should really not use that - it's crap. Instead: create a database in the SQL Server instance and use it by its logical name (instead of fiddling around with physical .mdf files....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the SQL Server Express, not the normal (non-express) one.

Quoting [this thread on MSDN social](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/6503fe05-4d05-49e7-8c2a-b9778ab7e9b8/):

> In particular, SSE has a number of options turned on that are
>   typically not on in higher versions of SQL Server.  You could turn
>   them on but wouldn't want to if you are using SQL Server as a general
>   server, not a local database store.  In addition, there is some
>   behavior that is unique to SSE that is particular to the way local
>   database stores are used.  But, to be quite clear, it is exactly the
>   same .exe.

Have a look at this SO thread, too: [Problem with creating .MDF file from Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650183/problem-with-creating-mdf-file-from-visual-studio-2010)