# Adding SQL Server database to Visual Studio 2013 ASP.Net webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

I am trying to add a SQL Server database item into my ASP.Net website.

I have SQL Server 2012 installed but when I press add in Visual Studio I get the following error

> Connection to SQL server database files (.mdf) require SQL Server 2005 Express or SQL Server 2008 Express to be installed and running on the local computer. The current version of SQL Server Express can be downloaded and at the following at the following URL: "

I am wondering if I can get it to work with 2012 in the way it would with 2005/2008 or will I need to download 2005/2008 to get this feature?

I only ask because it seems a little strange that VS2013 is not not compatible with SQL Server 2012...

PS: I am trying to follow the following tutorial and that is why I am hoping to get this to work so I can follow the tutorial as intended. "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tyr1YXpNOrk"

Comment: I think that you are trying to work with old mssql driver.

Comment: Refer this link for more detail
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358836/why-i-cant-create-sql-database-in-vs-2010

Answer (score -1):

> I am wondering if i can get it to work with 2012 in the way it would with 2005/2008

What for? To my knowledge that was retired for the bad issues it created.

- Visual Studio 2013 comes with an ad job user version of MSSQL (localdb) that is non-install-required and used in case.
- Otherwise install the normal sql server and reate the db - do not rely on this functionality (like most non-trivial shops anyway) and no problem arises to start.

Comment: So how do i add new database to the website then because when i try to go add new item> sql database i get that error above

Comment: Visual Studio requires SQL Server Express for the integration to work.  Using the full version of Sql or the developer version doesn't provide the integration.  Sql express 2012 should work.  You just have to install it, you don't have to use it.

Comment: I do not. I craete a website on my local database server. Why should I add it to the website? The website dconnects, but it does not control. Normally in larger scenarios the database ias even on a seaparate server.

Answer (score -1):

Yes It can be done through Visual studio and here is the link to guide A-Z 
It will IIS to deploy ASP site.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-(data)/creating-model-classes-with-linq-to-sql-cs

**Hope this will work** as it worked for me

Answer (score -1):

by **SQL Server Management Studio** create your database, then in vs 2013 asp.net project use this database into **web.config** file

---

in vs 2013 and **Server Explorer** tab and **Data Connections** with **Add Connection** or **Create new sql server database** use from your db or create new sql 2012 db

Comment: I downvoted this answer because it doesn't address the OP's question: they're asking about how they can use SQL Server Express _LocalDb_ (because they have an `.mdf` file) in the fact of VS's warning message telling them that they don't have SQL Server installed in the first place - which this answer misses completely.