# Using SQL Server 2008 R2 Express with C# Express 2010

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, visual-c#-express-2010

Wonder if SQL Server 2008 R2 Express edition can be used with C# Express 2010? I'm getting the error below when trying to add 'Service-based Database' item to my projects.

Please note, I've only got SQL Server 2008 **R2** Express.

**Update 1** - I checked the service (`MSSQLSERVER`) and it's up and running, I've got no errors during SQL Server 2008 R2 installation either, the PC didn't have any previous versions of SQL Server installed.

**The actual error:**

> *Connections to SQL Server database files (.mdf) require SQL Server
>   2005 Express or SQL Server 2008 Express to be installed and running on
>   the local computer.  The current version of SQL Server Express can be
>   downloaded at the following URL:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=125883*

Thanks.

Comment: What does your **connection string** look like? Also: you're not consistent - you mention the Express edition in your title, yet in the question you talk about **2008 R2** (not mentioning anything about "Express"), and the service name also seems to point to a non-Express version that's installed. So is it Express or not?

Comment: @marc_s I simply don't have a connection string as I don't have the actual database, I was hoping to create it in VS2010 Express.

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127359/how-to-add-sql-server-database-file-mdf-in-visual-studio-without-installing-s) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487067/connection-string-problem-with-new-asp-net-website-template).. Attaching to a database via `AttachDBFilename` is only possible when you use one of the Express editions of the product. So it won't work on the developer edition.

Since user instances will be removed in a future version of SQL Server, you probably shouldn't use this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the message says, Visual C# Express 2010 does not support connections to SQL Server 2008 R2 Express (which is not an upgrade to SQL Server 2008 Express). You could give Visual Studio 2012 a try.

EDIT: It seems like my above statement is not correct. I've tested it and I got SQL Server 2008 R2 Express working with Visual Studio 2010 Premium. So I guess it should also work in Visual C# Express 2010.

In order for it to work I had to change 'SQL Server Instance Name' found in the options under 'Database Tools' --> 'Data Connections'. The default value is SQLEXPRESS but I changed my instance name to SQLEXPRESS2008R2 during installation.

Comment: any offical proof by any chance? I can't use 2012 as I'm running on Win XP.

Comment: @user1514042 I read some MVP posts stating this though it seems like they were wrong (or they had another scenario). Please see my updated answer.